# Python PyQt4 Emitting and Receiving Custom signals

Tags: python, python-2.7, signals, pyqt4, signals-slots

I am aware that there are several questions about this topic. I have look through most of them but still can't figure out why I am having this problem.

Basically, what I am trying to do is: to show a busy indication progress bar (i.e `range (0,0)`) using a `QThread` class.

I am using `mysignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal()` to create my signal. And after that I use `mysignal.emit()` to transmit that signal. The signal is used to inform the main thread to stop the progress bar action.

This is how I connect that signal to one of my function `mysignal.connect(myfunction)`. But whenever I run my script, I have this error message.

```
AttributeError: 'PyQt4.QtCore.pyqtSignal' object has no attribute 'connect'
```

What is likely the cause of my problem?

FYI: I am using windows 8.1 with python 2.7.5

**EDIT:**

Simplify version of my code below:

```
class Main(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    .......
    .......
    self.progressBar = QtGui.QProgressBar(self)
    self.progressBar.setRange(0,1)
    button = QtGui.QPushButton('button')
    button.clicked.connect(self.onStart())

    def onStart(self):
        self.progressBar.setRange(0,0)
        self.LoadPage = LoadingThread()
        self.LoadPage.taskFinished.connect(self.onFinished)
        self.LoadPage.Load()

    def onFinished(self):
        self.progressBar.setRange(0,1)


class LoadingThread(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self):   
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)    
        self.taskFinished = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    def Load(self):
        #My stuffs here (to be executed duing the progress bar busy)
        time.sleep(5)
        self.taskFinished.emit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This smells like you're adding the signal to the class instance, rather than the class, which is not possible. Tried this myself just a few hours ago, getting the same error message...

Make sure the signal is defined on the class:

```
class Foo(QObject):

    mysignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
```

This does not work:

```
foo = Foo()
foo.mysignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
```

**EDIT :**

In your case, change LoadingThread to:

```
class LoadingThread(QtCore.QThread):

    taskFinished = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):   
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)    

    def Load(self):
        #My stuffs here (to be executed duing the progress bar busy)
        time.sleep(5)
        self.taskFinished.emit()
```

Comment: is it possible to call `setCentralWidget` method of my `Main` class from my `LoadingThread` class?

Comment: Nope. The recommended way to communicate with the GUI thread from other threads is using signals & slots. Check: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/thread-basics.html. If my answer solved your original issue, please accept it :)